# Batch file to verify to verify a .csv file

Tags: csv, validation, batch-file

I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction, in relation to the scenario I am faced with.

Essentially, I am given a csv each day containing payment information of 200+ lines

As the Payment reference is input by the user at source, this isn't always in the format I need.

The process is currently done manually, and can take considerable time, therefore I was hoping to come up with a batch file to isolate the reference I require, based on a set of parameters.

Each reference should be; 11 digits in length, be numeric only and start either 1,2 or 3.

I have attached a basic example with this post.

It may be that this isn't possible in batch, but any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Showing a clipped screenshot from a spreadsheet type program is absolutely no use to us here. We need to see the `.csv` file you want the script to read, especially it's layout and format, _(including any headers)_. Also this forum is where we help you with issues resulting from your own scripting efforts, it's not a free coding request service. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49200984/edit) to help make it on topic and within our guidelines.

Comment: The specific question in this post is a bit vague. But my best suggestion is to investigate regex  and how to write batch files.  The batch file wikipedia entry has some useful examples to get started with: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Batch_file_parameters

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure about batch but [Python](https://www.python.org/) and [Regex](https://regex101.com/)can help you out here.

- Here is a great [tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/csv/using-the-csv-module-in-python) on using csv's with python.
- Once you have that down, you could use [Regex](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to filter out the correct values.
- Here is the correct expression to help you out `^[1|2|3][0-9]{10}$`

Comment: Apologies @compo I was simply curious to know whether this was possible in batch and whether anyone was willing to share ideas. I have used batch before, but quite some time ago, and a little rusty. Thanks for your comments

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion James. I'll certainly give it a go. Many thanks